# Combinatorics Question involving answer choices and finding all cases with consecutive answers.

Tags: combinatorics

A student is taking a 12-question multiple choice test. Each question has 5 choices. How many ways can the student fill out the answer sheet so there is at least one place where two consecutive answers are the same?

So far, I understand how to get the total amount of possible combinations. But I am confused as to which method to take to try to implement the restriction. Do I try to find the amount of ways in which there are no places where two consecutive answers that are the same then subtract that from the total?

If so, how would I go about doing that.

Comment: Yes, that is a good strategy.  How many choices are there for the first question?  How many choices are there for each subsequent question if no two consecutive answers are the same?

Comment: Same as:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3216724/number-of-ways-an-answers-sheet-can-be-fill-with-at-least-two-consecutive-answer